# Locking read/write operations on a data structure in Scala/akka

Tags: scala, concurrency, locking, akka, locks

I have multiple actors (in the form of Futures) firing other futures off based on what they read from a single object's cache. I want to make sure that no work overlaps, and thus want to put a lock on all read/modify/write operations. How do I do this in Scala?

I tried this, but I don't want every method/function that accesses the cache to have to be synchronized, but rather have anything that tries to access the cache understand that it needs to wait until it's time for it to access.

```
//The cache    
object certCache {
  var cache = new HashMap[Char, Future[Boolean]]
}

def someMethod = synchronized {
   if(certCache ... ) 
   certCache.do(...)
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: I wouldn't use locking for this but have some kind of Observable (or event-based) mechanism to notify client that your futures have completed.

Comment: Put your single object behind an actor, so that anyone who wants to query it has to send the actor a message and wait for a reply? Then you don't need to synchronize, since an actor only handle one message at a time, so simultaneous access can never arise.

Comment: Cool! I'm doing that.

Answer (score 0):

### Agents

The akka library has a perfect solution for your question: [`Agents`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.4/index.html#akka.agent.Agent).  From the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/agents.html):

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import akka.agent.Agent

val agent = Agent(42)
```

To read from an Agent you can dereference them or call the get method, both of which are immediately returning synchronous calls:

```
val agentResult = agent()
val agentResult2 = agent.get
```

Updates are asynchronous:

```
agent send (_ + 10) //updates value to 52, eventually
```

Similarly, you can get a `Future` of the Agent's value which completes after the currently queued updates have completed:

```
val futureValue = agent.future
```

### Actors

Of course you can always go with a "home grown" solution and write an Actor that caches your values and responds to queries.  BUT, this is a much more manual/inefficient solution than Agents.

Actors should only be considered as a last resort when other akka/scala solutions do not apply.  This is because Actors are very low-level and the receive method is not compose-able.